# Why can't I change a substring within a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that will convert a dedicated word within a string into asterisks. Basically, I want to censor a word from a string (ex. change "Hello World" into "Hello *****" if I made "World" the dedicated word). I tried to write the following code, but the code will not convert words into asterisks.

```
def censor(text, word):

    a = text.split()

    replace = ""

    for i in word:
        replace += "*"

    for i in a:
        if i == word:
            i = replace

    result =' '.join(a)

    return result
```

Can someone help me? Everything in the code seems to work except for the line `i = replace`.

Thanks!

Comment: That line works fine, it just doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: More accurate question: Why can't you reassign a loop variable and have it persist?

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i = replace` rebinds the variable named `i` to the string in `replace`. It does not update the list as you seem to expect. You could fix your code by assigning `replace` to the item in the list using an index:

```
for idx, s in enumerate(a):
    if s == word:
        a[i] = replace
```

Now the item in the list `a` will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to change a substring in a string, you can use something like this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, '*'*len(word))
```

This will replace all instances of `word` with enough `*`s for the `len(word)`.

---

Just realizing the problem with my answer is that if you wanted to censor out "world" but not "worldbreaker", you would run into problems, cause you would end up with "*****breaker".

In this case, I would say to do something like:

```
censor(text, word):
    a = [w if w!=word else '*'*len(w) for w in text.split()]
    return ' '.join(a)
```

In the second line we let each `w`  (a word from `text.split()`) remain unless it is `word`, in which case we replace it with `*`'s enough to fill. Then we join it with spaces and return

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
def censor(text, word):
    a = text.split()
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        if v == word:
            a[i] = "*"*len(v)
    return  ' '.join(a)

print censor("Hello World", "World")
```

Output:

```
Hello *****
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `find()` method.

```
def replaceWord(word, sentence):
    # find the starting position
    posStart = sentence.find(word)

    # find the ending position
    posEnd = posStart + sentence[posStart:].find(" ") - 1

    # Get the word
    new_word = sentence[posStart:posEnd+1]

    # Turn word into a list
    list_word = list(new_word)

    # Find length of word
    word_length = len(sentence[posStart:posEnd + 1])

    # replace the word with "*"
    star = ""
    for i in list_word:
        star = star + i.replace(i, "*")

    # Add back in sentence
    new_sentence = sentence[0:posStart - 1] + " " + star + " " + sentence[posEnd +2:]
    return new_sentence

print(replaceWord("fox", "The fox is there"))
```